# Excel - result of =filter() in merged cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Sheet1 table is unmerged, except column A, where every `A3:A5`, `A6:A8`, `A9:A11` etc. are merged together. From another sheet I'd like to return data from column A with `=filter()`, but the result goes to Sheet!A:A ignoring the merge. How to force filter to drop first result in A3, second in A6, third in A9?

Right now second result goes to A4, third to A5 - when A3:A5 merged - I don't see them, when unmerged - it's shown. Is there any separator to ignore every 2 rows between results?

My formula in A3 (A1-Z2 are headers) to filter is:

```
=IF.ERROR(FILTER(Sheet2!$A$2:$A; Sheet2!$A$2:$A>1); "")
```

In advance - I use polish formulas and I am not sure is my english enough to clearly define my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I suggest you left the filter results (From A3 to A5), then try following formula in other column with no unmerged cells to check if you merge cells, will the result be correct.

`=INDEX($A$3:$A$5,QUOTIENT(ROW(),3),0)`

The formula results will be like the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why do you merge those cells?
You can get similar results without merging.
Look at the screenshot!
[image: Formulas in merged cells]